# How to know the count of repeated entries in Firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm creating a appointment app in flutter using firebase in which I have keep the track of people that got appointment repeatedly based on their phone number . How do I get this count of repeated entries?

Comment: Hi, your question seems unanswerable in its current state. What does your data structure or database layout look like?

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you add some code and more information to your question so we can can answer correctly but based on my understanding you want to check if this user repeatedly booked appointments using your app considering that it is a logged in user not a guest,

in this case inside your Firestore collection that contains the users i assume that each document represent a user add to each document (user information) a counter (integer variable) called for example "appointementsNumber" and every time a user book an appointment this counter will be increased by one, in this case you are able to know how many times this user booked an appointment.

hopefully i did understand your question correctly.